# Iterative algorithm to build triangles in a circumference

Tags: geometry

We start with a triangle with vertices $A$, $B$, and $C$ on a given circumference.

Now we want to find the midpoints of the sides: $M_{AB}$ (midpoint of $AB$), $M_{BC}$ (midpoint of $BC$), and $M_{CA}$ (midpoint of $CA$).
Draw lines from vertex $A \rightarrow M_{BC}$, from vertex $B \rightarrow M_{CA}$, and from vertex $C\rightarrow M_{AB}$, extending them to intersect the circumference at points $A'$, $B'$, and $C'$, respectively.
Construct a new triangle $\triangle A'B'C'$.

I want to proof the triangle converge to an equilateral triangle. One idea I had is proof that in each iteration the area increase, but I couldn’t prove that yet. Could some one help me with some idea.

I've discovered this property long time ago I did some simulations and it seems area increase in each iteration.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).